# cascaded query slows down drastically, but they work fine independently

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, subquery

Query 1:

```
select distinct email from mybigtable where account_id=345
```

takes 0.1s

Query 2:

```
Select count(*) as total from mybigtable where account_id=123 and email IN (<include all from above result>)
```

takes 0.2s

Query 3:

```
Select count(*) as total from mybigtable where account_id=123 and email IN (select distinct email from mybigtable where account_id=345)
```

takes 22 minutes and 90% its in the "preparing" state. Why does this take so much time.

Table is innodb with 3.2mil rows on MySQL 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation and with help from dba.se, this is the final query that worked majic.

```
select count(*) EmailCount from
(
    select tbl123.email from
    (select email from mybigtable where account_id=123) tbl123
    LEFT JOIN
    (select distinct email from mybigtable where account_id=345) tbl345
    using (email)
    WHERE tbl345.email IS NULL
) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more to this:

1. I suspect your query cache was warmed for queries 1 and 2, thus giving skewed results. Retry after `FLUSH QUERY CACHE;`
2. I suspect Query 3 will go via a temporary table, most possible on disk, while Query 2 is guaranteed to run from RAM. The default settings in my.cnf for temporary tables are very conservative.
3. Try this to make sure you are not hit by the old deoptimization bug in MySQL

.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT b.primary_key_column) AS total
FROM mybigtable a
INNER JOIN mybigtable b
ON a.email=b.email
WHERE a.account_id=345
AND b.account_id=123
```

Comment: I had suspected the same, I did a flush and tried again and the results are the same. What particular variables are you referring to ?

Comment: My max_heap_table_size = 67M
tmp_table_size = 67M .. Do you think I should change that ?

Comment: How many email addresses are we talking about (intermediate result)

Comment: 128 only. Also strange is that the explain on the query shows excellent plan and the state keeps showing "preparing" .. Is there a way I can see it in more detail something like strace for mysql ? profiler doesn't help as it shows the same "preparing" state

Comment: tried the join earlier too.. it takes forever, doesn't complete until 30 mins and I had to kill it :(

Comment: Yes, email has an index and do does the account_id (although none are primary key)

Comment: Are you sure your join version was like mine? I can't test, I don't have 3mil rows ...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is really bad at subqueries in IN clauses.  I would rewrite it as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total
FROM mybigtable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT email
    FROM mybigtable
    WHERE account_id = 345
) x
ON t.email = x.email
WHERE t.account_id=123
```